# Using an Array in another activity

Tags: android, arrays

Android novice, is it possible to create a String array in one activity and pass the contents of this array, so I can use this within another activity? If so how?

The following is my first activity.

```
    public class Screen2 extends MyActivity implements TextWatcher, View.OnClickListener { EditText quizNameText;
 EditText quesText;
 EditText correctAnsText;
 EditText hintText;
 int index=0;
 Button saveAndNext;
 protected String yourQuizName;
 public String[]
    question = new String[3];
 public String[] answer = new String[3];
 public String[] hint = new String[3];
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
 quizNameText = (EditText)
    findViewById(R.id.enterquiztitle);
 quesText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterqueshere);
 correctAnsText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entercorrectans);
 hintText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hintText);
 quizNameText.setText(yourQuizName);
 quesText.setText(question[0]);

    correctAnsText.setText(answer[0]);
 hintText.setText(hint[0]);
 saveAndNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourNextQuesAndSave);
 saveAndNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Question added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } });
 } @Override public void onClick(View v) { } @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { } @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int before, int count) { } @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { } I want to use it within the following;
 public class Screen4 extends Screen2 implements View.OnClickListener { TextView testBumbleTitle;
 TextView testBumbleQues;
 TextView
    testEnterAns;
 TextView testQuesHint;
 Button yourNextQuesandSave;
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.screen4);
 testBumbleTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testBumbleTitle);

    testBumbleQues = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testBumbleQues);
 testQuesHint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testQuesHint);
 testEnterAns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testEnterAns);
 yourNextQuesandSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourNextQuesAndSave);

    testBumbleTitle.setText(yourQuizName);
 for (int i=0;i
```

Comment: Please indent your code, if you want us to read it. Anyway, **yes**, there are some ways to do that. The **easisest** one is to share your array. Make it **protected** instead of private.

Comment: You should indent your code; right now your question is bordering on 'very low quality', which is generally deleted.  I'm hoping you'll take this opportunity to indent your code.  Specifically, use four spaces for each tab, and use the "Ctrl+K" or the `{}` icon to do so.

Answer (score 3):

you should put your array as extra to your `Intent`

```
intent.putExtra("string-array", stringArray);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in second activity :

```
String [] stringArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string-array");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `intent`

**In current activity:**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), classYouAreMovingTo.class);
myIntent.putExtra("myarray", myArray);
startActivity(myIntent);`
```

**In activity you are retrieving data (in this example it is classYouAreMovingTo)**

```
Intent previousScreenIntent = getIntent();
String[] myArray =  previousScreenIntent.getStringArrayExtra("myarray");
```